# How to restart mysql server?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mysql-python, bitnami

Every time I restart MySQL server

```
bitnami@xxx:/$ sudo opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start server
```

```
WWarning: World-writable config file '/opt/bitnami/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
Warning: World-writable config file '/opt/bitnami/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
121120 12:30:18 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log'.
121120 12:30:18 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/bitnami/mysql/data
121120 12:30:20 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/ip-10-136-14-170.pid ended
/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  could not be started
```

The server responds with the following error:

> (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)")

Please tell me what I have to do fix this issue.

Comment: This seems like it belongs on serverfault

Comment: If mysql is installed as a service (which is most of the time) you can do `service mysqld restart` or `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`.
I don't know anything of amazon/aws or mysql-python or bitnami, but you can try.

Comment: not really a programming question, off topic on stackoverflow. try 'chmod 0644 /opt/bitnami/mysql/my.cnf' and restart. if it doesn't help -> serverfault

Comment: @Martin Thanks alot you save my lot of hours. It works.

Comment: I will add it as answer, then you can accept it and everyone can see that it's the solution.

Comment: Where can questions related to amazon be posted?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If mysql is installed as a service (which is most of the time) you can do `service mysqld restart` or `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`.

You can also use `start`, `stop` or `reload` instead of `restart`.

Comment: Also, depending on distro `/etc/init.d/mysql restart` (Debian 5.0.10)